# What means --clearmodifiers in i3 config

Tags: i3-wm

I feel so stupid .. What means `--clearmodifiers` in i3 config?

I got this

```sh
#bindsym --release mod1+Shift+Left exec --no-startup-id xdotool key --clearmodifiers Shift+Home                         
#bindsym --release mod1+Shift+Right exec --no-startup-id xdotool key --clearmodifiers Shift+End
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an argument to i3, but rather an argument to [xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool), which is the program launched with the `exec` directive. The [xdotool manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html#clearmodifiers) explains the purpose of the `clearmodifiers` command:

> Any command taking the `--clearmodifiers` flag will attempt to clear any active input
> modifiers during the command and restore them afterwards.
>
> For example, if you were to run this command:
> `xdotool key a`
>
> The result would be 'a' or 'A' depending on whether or not you were holding the shift key
> on your keyboard. Often it is undesirable to have any modifiers active, so you can tell
> *xdotool* to clear any active modifiers.
>
> The order of operations if you hold shift while running `xdotool key --clearmodifiers a`
> is this:
>
> 1. Query for all active modifiers (finds shift, in this case)
> 2. Try to clear shift by sending 'key up' for the shift key
> 3. Runs normal `xdotool key a`
> 4. Restore shift key by sending 'key down' for shift
>
> The `--clearmodifiers` flag can currently clear of the following:
>
> - any key in your active keymap that has a modifier associated with it.  (See
>   xmodmap(1)'s `xmodmap -pm` output)
> - mouse buttons (1, 2, 3, 4, and 5)
> - 'caps lock'